# Coverage on new code & leak period

Tags: sonarqube

We are using SonarQube 5.6 with SonarJava plugin 4.12.

I was wondering how the measure **Coverage on new code** (used in the quality gate) is actually calculated.

Does SonarQube calculate it based on "the new code since the leak period"? Or is the last analysis (= last commit) the basis for the calculation?

All projects are using the leak period "previous_version" and most of them have defined versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis is code changed in the leak period.